# How could I display a bunch of small bitmaps in one image file, preferably a pdf

Tags: android, image, bitmap, pdf-generation

My app has a Report screen that includes a bunch of small bitmap images. I want to be able to take those images, and put them all into a single image file (formatted properly so that they are not overlapping) for viewing, but I'm unsure of how to go about it. I'm trying to prevent having a separate file for each image if possible. Does anyone know how this could be achieved? I'm not looking for someone to do it for me, but just give me a nudge in the right direction.

Comment: If I didn't understand correctly, you want to show bitmaps to your users in an activity? GridView can be useful for you.

Comment: @OzgurGUL Thanks for the reply, but what I'm trying to do is save a set of bitmaps in my app to a single image file. They are in the activity now, I want to save them to a file for viewing later on.